# How to load an html (navigation menu) inside an html (index.html) while it apply the css to the loaded navigation menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am learning Bootstrap, jQuery, React, to load my navigation menu that is in a different file `menu.html` from `index.html`, this is the script I use:

```
function codeAddress() {
  document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "src/menu.html";
}
window.onload = codeAddress;
```

and this is the basic of the HTML:

```
<body>
    <iframe id="myFrame" src="#" style="border:none;height:100%;width:100%;"></iframe>
</body>
```

The file loads, but the CSS is not apply to it, it looks like any normal list without any kind of design apply to it (aka, ugly), is there an easier method to do it or how to apply the css to that ugly thing? it looks perfect if the code is directly paste into the `index.html`.

The content of the `menu.html` is a simple list, something like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
 <!-- Brand -->
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://mydomain.ml/">M62</a>

 <!-- Links -->
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">keeper</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

I also try many other things, like html import, or javascript .get and none worked, this is the only code that actually loaded something from the menu file.

Comment: I also add the links and scripts to the menu file and did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

¿Did you include the css styles on the loaded html?